# Testing a C program through subprocess.Popen in PYTHON, raises cygwin error

Tags: python, c, testing, cygwin, popen

I am a student studying C right now and i have been trying to write test programs for my peers.
I decided to write my test program in python due to knowing that all of the students have the same IDE and interpreter version.

I decided to work with subprocess.Popen.
I unpack a tar file in that my C program is stored in using a tar command, then i compile the needed files using a gcc command. and then i run tests using input that is stored in text files, comparing the users output to expected outputs in corresponding text files.

when i run my C executable through the cmd, it works flawlessly and no errors appear.
but when i try to run them through subprocess.Popen, i get a cygwin error **in addition** to the expected output, causing my testing program to report a test failure.

I use this function, supplying it with an array of strings as arguments for the command.

```
def run_cmd_command(arguments_list):
        """
        runs the given command through the command line and returns information
        about the command.
        :param arguments_list: a list representing the command to run
        :return: A tuple containing the returncode, the output of the command and
        all the errors.
        """
        process = subprocess.Popen(arguments_list, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                           universal_newlines=True)
        output, errors = process.communicate()
        return process.returncode, output, errors
```

The test python program works properly when supplied with proper inputs.

On the other hand, when the inputs are not proper, the C program is supposed to print into stderr the string : `"Invalid Input\n"` but prints `Invalid input
      0 [main] TreeAnalyzer 1780 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to TreeAnalyzer.exe.stackdump`

I would like to supply you with more information but im not sure which information to supply due to not understand where the problem's may root from.

Comment: Most likely there is an issue in your C program. I would suggest to try a very simple C program, like Hello World to test your workflow first.

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll try that and post an update

Comment: Are you using cygwin's python3? Supply the version from `python -V` or `python3 -V` and the cygwin version info from `uname -a`. Also, I suggest you use the Cygwin mintty console instead of windows cmd, Also strongly suggest you use python3 (version 3) as python (version 2) is EOL this Dec 31.

Comment: If you're using Python 3 you can just use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) which is effectively the same as this.  I agree with others that this likely has little to do with Python; rather your C program is crashing for some reason.  Please try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or else it's hard to say much.

Comment: Thanks for the tip in the right direction guys, it was a C problem. 
Once I tested it with valgrind with all possible flags it found some error that apperarently Clion AND the command line did not.

So I could get better, any idea why Clion or the command file wouldn't tell me of errors in my code that got it stuck ? I tried freeing a non existing item and did not close a file properly. 

Also - as I'm new here, how do I give you credit for helping me out?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: When compiling with gcc it is good practice to use option `-Wall` so than all warnings are enabled